# pgfplots: using pi in foreach

Tags: pgfplots

How can I use pi the number in a `\foreach` in `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass[tikz, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \v/\colo in {0/red, {pi/4}/blue, {pi/2}/orange, {3*pi/4}/green,
      {5*pi/4}/Purple, {3*pi/2}/Salmon, {7pi/4}/SeaGreen}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\colo, domain = 0:2*pi]
      ({(exp(x) + exp(-x)) / 2 * cos(deg(\v))},
      {(exp(x) - exp(-x)) / 2 * sin(deg(\v))});
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want `v` to be a multiple of `pi` but

```
ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `p' or `pi' (in '(exp(x) + exp(-x)\
) / 2 * cos(deg(7pi/4))').
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{7pi/4}
```

should have a *

```
{7*pi/4}
```

Comment: Some of the plots are appearing dashed when that isn't an option.  Do you know why that would be?  I had to change the domain to `-5:5` or else there was a dimension too large error.

Comment: @dustin by default, from the sixth `\addplot` on, the line changes to a dashed style. To override this, add the `solid` option: `[\colo, solid, domain = 0:2*pi]`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina good job you answered that, my knowledge of pgf_anything_ is somewhat sketchy:-)